# Decrementing last string element in array without removing it in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, game-development, decrement

I'm currently doing a demo on Unity where I've put the whole alphabet in an array. For the backspace function I want to decremt the last string element in the array, but it doesnt work.

```
[SerializeField] private GameObject keyboard;

[SerializeField] private Text keyboardInput;

private KeyCode[] MyKeys = {KeyCode.A, KeyCode.B,KeyCode.C,KeyCode.D, KeyCode.E,KeyCode.F,KeyCode.G,KeyCode.H,KeyCode.I,KeyCode.J,KeyCode.K,KeyCode.L,KeyCode.M,KeyCode.N,KeyCode.O,KeyCode.P,KeyCode.Q,KeyCode.R,KeyCode.S,KeyCode.T, KeyCode.U ,KeyCode.V,KeyCode.W,KeyCode.X,KeyCode.Y,KeyCode.Z, KeyCode.Space, KeyCode.Backspace };

private string[] currText;
void Start()
{
    keyboardInput.text = currText.ToString();
}

private void typeKeys()
{

    for (var i = 0; i < MyKeys.Length; i++)
    {

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(MyKeys[i]))
        {

            if (i == 0)
            {
                keyboardInput.text += "a";
            }
            else if (i == 1)
            {
                keyboardInput.text += "b";
            }
            else if (i == 2)
            {
                keyboardInput.text += "c";
            }
            else if (i == 3)
            {
                keyboardInput.text += "d";
            }
            else if (i == 4)
            {
                keyboardInput.text += "e";
            }
            else if (i == 5)
            {
                keyboardInput.text += "f";
            }
            else if (i == 6)
            {
                keyboardInput.text += "g";
            }
            else if (i == 7)
            {
                keyboardInput.text += "h";
            }
            else if (i == 8)
            {
                keyboardInput.text += "i";
            }
            else if (i == 9)
            {
                keyboardInput.text += "j";
            }
            else if (i == 10)
            {
                keyboardInput.text += "k";
            }
            else if (i == 11)
            {
                keyboardInput.text += "l";
            }
            else if (i == 12)
            {
                keyboardInput.text += "m";
            }
            else if (i == 13)
            {
                keyboardInput.text += "n";
            }
            else if (i == 14)
            {
                keyboardInput.text += "o";
            }
            else if (i == 15)
            {
                keyboardInput.text += "p";
            }
            else if (i == 16)
            {
                keyboardInput.text += "q";
            }
            else if (i == 17)
            {
                keyboardInput.text += "r";
            }
            else if (i == 18)
            {
                keyboardInput.text += "s";
            }
            else if (i == 19)
            {
                keyboardInput.text += "t";
            }
            else if (i == 20)
            {
                keyboardInput.text += "u";
            }
            else if (i == 21)
            {
                keyboardInput.text += "v";
            }
            else if (i == 22)
            {
                keyboardInput.text += "w";
            }
            else if (i == 23)
            {
                keyboardInput.text += "x";
            }
            else if (i == 24)
            {
                keyboardInput.text += "y";
            }
            else if (i == 25)
            {
                keyboardInput.text += "z";
            }
            else if (i == 26)
            {
                keyboardInput.text += " ";
            }
            else if (i == 27)
            {
                currText = currText.Take(currText.Length - 1).ToArray();
            }
        }
    };
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

    typeKeys();
}
```

This is the part im trying to get to work

```
                else if (i == 27)
            {
                currText = currText.Take(currText.Length - 1).ToArray();
            }
```

[See video for clarification](https://www.loom.com/share/89cf77ac8b4e4f4b9ea23fc6f0146dfc)

What I mean by that it **doesnt work** is that I cant remove the last letter from my array thus giving the effect of using backspace in a sentence in my virtual setup. This is the whole script.

Comment: What does "it doesnt work" mean?

Comment: All i see from your code is you are always adding to your "keyboardInput" variable. In which point are you adding to your "currText" variable ? From your code i can say it is always an empty string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start by reducing the amount of code. And then, after that, we can also take advantage of two facts; Unity has a KeyCode enum, and the alphabet is ordered in values from 'a' through to 'a'+25. I'll clarify that with a bit of code:

```
private Text keyboardInput;
List<char> charList = new List<char> ( );

private void typeKeys( )
{
    var length = charList.Count;

    if ( Input.GetKeyDown ( KeyCode.Space ) )
        charList.Add ( ' ' );

    if ( Input.GetKeyDown ( KeyCode.Backspace ) && length  > 0 )
        charList.RemoveAt ( length - 1 );

    for ( var i = 0; i < 26; i++ )
        if ( Input.GetKeyDown ( KeyCode.A + i ) ) charList.Add ( ( char ) ( 'a' + i ) );

    if ( length != charList.Count ) keyboardInput.text =  string.Concat ( charList );
}
```

What I'm doing here, is first checking for the Space key, followed by the Backspace key. After that, I iterate through the alphabet characters, adding the `i` value to the `KeyCode.A`. Remember that enums are just `int` by default. If that's a match, we add the corresponding `i` value to the 'a' character and add that to the `List<char>` list, remembering to also cast the resulting value back to a `char` first.

Finally, if the length of your character array has changed, then, and only then, do we update your `keyboardInput.text`. That's to help save string garbage being produced every single frame. We can `Concat` a `char` IEnumerable to a `string`.

Using this method you can remove the whole line that starts with `private KeyCode[] MyKeys`. You don't need to store all of the `KeyCode` values in an array to check against.

Comment: Wow! What a great Solution! I'm fairly new to C# so I have no prior experience with enums or the **List** system. I'm used to only working within the spectrum of arrays but this was an eye opener :). Thank you for your help! There is still a lot to be done since I'm trying to implement det å, ä, ö keys (this demo is based on a swedish keyboard) but this was a great start. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer to your question, and to get a proper answer you'll need to post your complete code and a good explanation of what's going wrong, but I thought I'd post this as it might be useful to you.

I've refactored you `typeKeys()` method.

```
private void typeKeys()
{
    foreach (var key in MyKeys.Where(k => k != KeyCode.Space).Where(k => k != KeyCode.Backspace))
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(key))
        {
            keyboardInput.text += key.ToString().ToLower();
        }
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        keyboardInput.text += " ";
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Backspace))
    {
        currText = currText.Take(currText.Length - 1).ToArray();
    }
}
```

That's it.

The line `currText = currText.Take(currText.Length - 1).ToArray();` should work to truncate a properly defined array by one element or simply keep it at zero elements.

Comment: Way more readable. I do think it needs a condition in the `if (Input.GetKeyDown(key))` block to handle the case where `k == KeyCode.Space`